# How to write unit tests for mocked Store selectors in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ngrx

I'm starting to add Store into existing project and faced issue while trying to write uti tests for component.

I'm facing issue while mocking `selector` - In the `console.log` I can see, that `getIsLoadingState` is returning value of `true`, but I'm facing error:

```
      Array [
        Object {
          "frame": 0,
          "notification": Object {
    -       "error": undefined,
    -       "kind": "N",
    -       "value": true,
    +       "error": [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isLoading')],
    +       "kind": "E",
    +       "value": undefined,
          },
        },
      ]
```

if I uncomment `provideMockStore` part to be:

```js
provideMockStore({
  initialState: {
    [mediaResourcesFeatureKey]: {
      isLoading: false,
    },
  },
}),
```

then I don't get any errors, but it seems that the last result of `selector` would always be the actual value provided in `initialState`. console.log prints out 2 results: true, false.

This way I'm not able to check different cases (toggle between true/false results, while doing `ovverideSelector`) and I would be working with full set/state which I don't want to.

What is the correct approach for testing `selectors` on component without actually providing  the whole state model and with a possibility to change selectors result value for different test cases while, not "reseting" testing module with different state

current setup:

*app.module.ts*

```js
imports: [
  StoreModule.forRoot(
    {
      [mediaResourcesFeatureKey]: mediaResourcesReducer,
    },
    {},
  ),
]
```

*media-resources.reducers.ts*

```js
export const mediaResourcesFeatureKey: string = 'mediaResources';

export interface IMediaResourcesState {
  isLoading: boolean;
}

export const initialState: IMediaResourcesState = {
  isLoading: false,
};

const reducer: ActionReducer<IMediaResourcesState> = createReducer<IMediaResourcesState>(
  initialState,
  on(fetchMediaResources, (state: IMediaResourcesState) => ({
    ...state,
    isLoading: true,
  })),
  on(fetchMediaResourcesSuccess, (state: IMediaResourcesState) => ({
    ...state,
    isLoading: false,
  })),
);

export function mediaResourcesReducer(
  state: IMediaResourcesState = initialState,
  action: Action,
): IMediaResourcesState {
  return reducer(state, action);
}
```

*media-resources.selectors.ts*

```js
export const getMediaResourcesState: MemoizedSelector<object, IMediaResourcesState> =
  createFeatureSelector<IMediaResourcesState>(mediaResourcesFeatureKey);

export const getIsLoadingState: MemoizedSelector<object, boolean> = createSelector(
  getMediaResourcesState,
  (state: IMediaResourcesState) => state.isLoading,
);
```

*file-list.component.ts*

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'file-list',
  templateUrl: './file-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./file-list.component.scss'],
})
export class FileListComponent {
  // trying to test `isLoading$`
  isLoading$: Observable<boolean> = this.store$.pipe(
    select(getIsLoadingState),
    tap((data: any) => console.log('data', data)),
  );

  constructor(private store$: Store<{}>) {}

// other stuff
```

*file-list.component.spec.ts*

```js
describe('FileListComponent', () => {
  let component: FileListComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FileListComponent>;
  let mockStore: MockStore;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [FileListComponent],
      imports: [TranslateModule.forRoot()],
      providers: [
        provideMockStore({
          // initialState: {
          //   [mediaResourcesFeatureKey]: {
          //     isLoading: false,
          //   },
          // },
        }),
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FileListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    mockStore = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
    mockStore.overrideSelector(getIsLoadingState, true);

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  fit('should set isLoading stream', () => {
    expect(component.isLoading$).toBeObservable(hot('a', { a: true }));
  });
});
```

**Update**

angular v14.2
ngrx v12.4
jest v28.1

adding setup files aswell

*setup-jest.js*

```js
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
import '@angular/localize/init';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

beforeAll(() => {
  TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();
  TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting(), {
    teardown: { destroyAfterEach: false },
  });
});
```

*tsconfig.json*

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "lib": ["es2018", "es2019", "dom", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["src/app/*"],
      "@modules/*": ["src/app/modules/*"],
      "@shared/*": ["src/app/modules/shared/*"],
      "@env/*": ["src/environments/*"],
      "@mocks/*": ["mocks/*"],
      "@angular/*": ["./node_modules/@angular/*"],
      "@gnw/*": ["./node_modules/@gnw/*"],
      "@flex-layout": ["./node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/*"],
      "@jest-mocks": ["jest-mocks.ts"],
      "@app-store": ["src/app/store/index.ts"]
    },
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

*tsconfig.spec.json*

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": ["jest", "node"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": false,
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["src/app/*"],
      "@modules/*": ["src/app/modules/*"],
      "@shared/*": ["src/app/modules/shared/*"],
      "@env/*": ["src/environments/*"],
      "@mocks/*": ["mocks/*"],
      "@angular/*": ["./node_modules/@angular/*"],
      "@gnw/*": ["./node_modules/@gnw/*"],
      "@flex-layout": ["./node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/*"],
      "@jest-mocks": ["jest-mocks.ts"],
      "@app-store": ["src/app/store/index.ts"]
    }
  },
  "files": ["src/setup-jest.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```